# Should I store all mysql query in another php file?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a php file to store mysql user name and password for security reason, and it is included in every page. How about all mysql statement? Should I also have another php file to store all mysql statements, so even if a page has unexpected error, people cannot see the mysql query content?

Comment: You shouldn't have PHP configured to send error messages to the browser in production.

Comment: in a production env set `error_reporting(0)` and in a dev env `error_reporting(E_ALL)` or whatever other types of messages you want to see. That will prevent the users seeing problems with queries and other coding issues.

Comment: In addition with @mic message, you should gracefully tell the user that something, somewhere, went wrong and ask them to contact someone for further help.

Comment: ok thanks. So store mysql queries in another php file is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

create two error files in the name of **404.php** , **500.php** and also create a .htaccess file in your main directory. and add these two lines of code

```
   ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
   ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
```

this will prevent the user from seeing the unexpected errors.